# Is there a way to externally prevent a program from stealing input feedback?

Tags: windows, input

Recently, the developers of a piece of development software I use decided that their software was going to start stealing input feedback. By stealing input feedback, I mean it intercepts key presses and refuses to tell Windows/other programs that the key was pressed. They seem to have done a good job at whitelisting Windows keyboard shortcuts (Ctrl+Shift+Esc, Alt+F4, the Windows key, etc), but their sudden choice to steal mouse/keyboard input has prevented autohotkey scripts I created from detecting key presses, effectively breaking them. I asked the software developers to revert the change to the input stealing, explaining what it had caused, but they replied "no".

For this program and software that, like it, steal mouse/keyboard input (e.g. Skyrim), is there any way to externally disallow the program to capture feedback? As in allow it to detect input, but any requests to withhold the input from other programs would be ignored.

Comment: That allows AHK to pick up input -- thanks! What about Skyrim capturing input though? I can't exactly run Windows as an administrator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Run AutoHotKey elevated**, i.e. "as administrator".
If the other software is not running elevated, AutoHotKey should get keystrokes with priority.

If by Skyrim you mean a computer game, I would recommend asking at [gaming SE](http://gaming.stackexchange.com), because many times, game players have found their ways around particular game titles (even know-how on controlling and macros).